# R Language - The average number of steps to get number

Tags: r

I have sequence of the numbers(Really it is just a piece of this sequence. In fact I have over 100k numbers)

> 1 2 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 1 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 1 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 2 3

I need to calculate the average number of steps after I get 1 in this sequence.
For example:
In this sequence 1 is first number. Now I count number of steps to get next 1 and I get 9. Next 1 is after 13 steps, next after 15 steps etc.

Now I have to calculate the average number of steps.
So there we have (9+13+15)/3= 12.(3)

How I can do this in R Language?

Comment: `mean(diff(which(x == 1)))`???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll find that you get much more positive results if you include things you have tried in your question. Otherwise, you will be informed that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Thanks Ananda! It works. It is Markov Chain and I generated this with assumption that 1 is always first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
mean(diff(which(x == 1)))
## [1] 12.33333
```

Given:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 
    3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 
    3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks Ananda Mahto! It works. It is Markov Chain and I generated this with assumption that 1 is always first